# How to access a file from another activity

Tags: android, file, android-camera

I try to take pictures from camera and then I am trying to access these `two files` created over here in another activity with the help of `fileProvider()` method that I have written below, but to my bad it always shows me null at the receving point. Can some one please help me how to access the files in different activity that are created over here?

```
  public class FileGenerator extends Activity {
        File image1,image2,image3,image4;
        private String imagePath1,imagePath2,imagePath3,imagePath4;

        ....................
       .........................

    public void cameraShot() // This method would be called when the user clicks on a button on my activity to make a request of taking pic.
        {

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                //startActivityForResult(intentPicture,ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE);

                Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                if(flipvalue == 0)
                {
                    intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, firstCapturedImageURI);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "testingimage1.jpg");
                    firstCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    startActivityForResult(intentPicture,CAMERA_DATA_FIRST);
                }

                if(flipvalue == 1)
                {
                    intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, secondCapturedImageURI);
                    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "testingimage2.jpg");
                    secondCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                    startActivityForResult(intentPicture,CAMERA_DATA_SECOND);


                }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {
                Bundle extras= data.getExtras();

                if(requestCode == 0)
                {
                    if(bitMap1 != null)
                    bitMap1.recycle();
                    bitMap1 = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                    imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitMap1);

                    selectedImagePath1 = getRealPathFromURI(firstCapturedImageURI);

                    imagePath1 = selectedImagePath1;
                    Log.d("Pic Path>>>", selectedImagePath1);

                    image1 = new File(selectedImagePath1);

                    flipvalue =1;

                }
                           if (requestCode == 1)
                {
                    if(bitMap2 != null)
                    bitMap2.recycle();
                    bitMap2 = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
                    imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitMap2);

                    selectedImagePath2 = getRealPathFromURI(secondCapturedImageURI);

                    imagePath2 = selectedImagePath2;
                    Log.d("Pic Path>>>", selectedImagePath2);
                    image2 = new File(selectedImagePath2);

                    flipvalue =2;

                }
    }

protected File fileProvider(int i)
    {
        if(i==1)
        return image1;
        else
        return image2;


    }

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the activity where I try to receive these files.

```
public class FileReceiver extends Activity{
File receivedimage1, receivedimage2;
FileGenerator filegen = new FileGenerator();
               ..........................
                   ............................

           receivedimage1 = filegen.fileProvider(1);
            Log.d("File 1 ","file1 object"+receivedimage1);// always shows null

            receivedimage2 = filegen.fileProvider(2);
             Log.d("File 2 ","file2 object"+receivedimage2);// shows null

}
```

**P.S.** -- Before trying this, I used to take the strings(i.e., `selectedImagePath1, selectedImagePath2`) to another activity, then used these strings to create files. But don't know why this somehow corrupts my image files that I create. So, I followed the above code way, still no luck.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I can't because I should send the data through arraylist which is of String type only as I have another data to send as strings. Moreover I can't use intent as it is not a direct activity that I have to start from this activity. Can you suggest me some other way?

Comment: @Alex_ios What is _not a direct activity_? How about building an Android app on concepts which Android provides? ;)

Comment: @ClassStacker What I meant was the receiving activity cannot be started from this first activity through intent. Rather this is 1st activity and receiving activity is 3rd activity. i.e., 1-->2-->3.

Comment: And why do you want to pass the file _content_ instead of the file name? Or am I getting this wrong?

Comment: I tried sending the paths previously, but thought it was wrong way, but now I came to know it's actually because my files are getting corrupted. Please read my P.S. So, now I came to know I was correct but still the problem is with files itself.

Comment: Funny idea. On a mobile device, you would try to load a couple of pictures into memory, rather than trying to find out why they get corrupted on storage. Must be your first app, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use Intent for sending file paths to other Activities and if you have more then two Activity then use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for Stroring files path and retrive paths in other Activities from SharedPreferences. you can store paths in SharedPreferences as :

```
 SharedPreferences pathPrefs = FileGenerator.this.getSharedPreferences(
                                             "filepathPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = pathPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("image1",image1.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        prefsEditor.putString("image2",image2.getAbsolutePath().toString());
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

and in other Activities get file paths from SharedPreferences as:

```
SharedPreferences pathPrefs = 
                   this.getSharedPreferences("filepathPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
String image1 = pathPrefs.getString("image1", "defaultpath");
String image2 = pathPrefs.getString("image2", "defaultpath");
// now use both file path in your code..
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for your response. But this fetches me the path in string form. How can I use this string to get the file? Because in the receiving activity, I have to keep like new FileBody(file1); So, in this line I need to give file as parameter.

Comment: @Alex_ios : yes just pass string to `File file1 = new File(image1); new FileBody(file1);` to get file

Comment: Actually it's my file getting corrupted while sending. So, what I did with storing the paths in the arraylist also works fine. Don't know why it's happening :(